# MongoDB smallfiles

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a simple question concerning **smallfiles** parameter of a MongoDB instance.

I have a **MongoDB 2.4.4** instance with **smallfiles** set to **false**. Because of that I already have 50 GB of data on that instance.

If I set **smallfiles** to **true**, will that space be reduced or will I have to backup, drop and import the DBs?

Thank you

Comment: Please ask any questions regarding maintenance and administration of MongoDB on https://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion was that that the space wasn't reduced automatically, so you need to backup, drop and import the DBs

Thank you